# CSS doesn't load right away when website is hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.net website on IIS, and whenever I first view the webpage directly through the IIS manager or even by it's hosted name, it only loads the content of the web page, and not the CSS. I have to refresh it in order for the page to be position correctly.

Has anyone else had this problem and know of a way I can fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try with Fiddler or any other equivalent tool?

Comment: Oh, I found out what Fiddler is! I will try it out.

Comment: @onof do you have any experience with Fiddler? I get a 404 error next to my css file when I try and load the page. Why might it do this?

Comment: 404 means "not found". The client can't download the file. Check file permissions, check that the path (shown in fiddler) is valid and right.

Comment: @onof No, it's really weird. There's nothing wrong with the file permissions... It just never understands that the css file is there when first loading the website or when clearing the cache.